# Export cropped HTML table from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I only need the actual table exported from a Google spreadsheet. Cropping the HTML from [HTML export](https://sites.google.com/a/temple.edu/googleapps1/tip-of-the-day/april28-exportagooglespreadsheetintovariousformats) manually means lots of work.

[This document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bjZSGwYfnF_wG6qVzDLlpzBzIAdtK3kLzqJ2xidVE4/edit#gid=0) contains two tables, and these must occur in different places of my work.

[image: Google spreadsheet]

I spent quite a time to separate the table you see highlighted. Isn't there an easier way than rewriting it? The other table is quite large and rewriting it would kill me. I think even writing JavaScript code for it would be faster...

Can I just export the spreadsheet selection to HTML?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this question belong on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. What's the tag [google-spreadsheets](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) doing here? I actually first checked for that tag before writing the question...

Comment: I'd like to note that some of your grammar corrections are probably quite discutable. Are you a native (british) english speaker?